# Ambiguous invoking error between the method itself?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I defined a **IsNumeric()** extension function for **DataColumn**, and in my code i am doing something like

```
if(column.IsNumeric())
{
  .............
}
```

When I compile it, Visual Studio gave me this weird error:

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:         

'EO.Public.ExtensionMethods.IsNumeric(System.Data.DataColumn)' and  

'EO.Public.ExtensionMethods.IsNumeric(System.Data.DataColumn)'
```

You can see the two ambiguous methods are the same one. How could this happen?

Comment: Could two different DLL's have that method defined in the same namespace?

Comment: do you have a overloaded method of `IsNumeric()` in same dll accepting different parameters?

Comment: Thank you! neontapir. you are right. I have a cs file and added to different projects as linked file. This caused my problem.